# matlab: legend; CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent

Tags: matlab, user-interface, legend, strcat

I have a weird problem... I can't make legend: Lets say I have:

```
    fraction1Str = strcat('F1 = ', sprintf('%g',round(fraction1*100)/100), '+/-',sprintf('%g',round(fraction1STD*100)/100));
    fraction2Str = strcat('F2 = ', sprintf('%g',round(fraction2*100)/100), '+/-',sprintf('%g',round(fraction2STD*100)/100));
    fraction3Str = strcat('F3 = ', sprintf('%g',round(fraction3*100)/100), '+/-',sprintf('%g',round(fraction3STD*100)/100));

    fractionStr = [fraction1Str; fraction2Str; fraction3Str];
    ...
    hleg = legend(fractionStr);
```

That is giving me error: CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

All strings are the same format, even number of chars... Interestingly if I change to one of i.e.

```
fractionStr = [fraction3Str; fraction3Str; fraction3Str];
fractionStr = [fraction2Str; fraction2Str; fraction2Str];
fractionStr = [fraction1Str; fraction1Str; fraction1Str];
```

its working, but no with these three different strings... Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `fractionStr = char(fraction1Str, fraction2Str, fraction3Str);` without having to worry about length of individual string.

Comment: Also instead of `sprintf`, you can use `num2str(fraction1,'%3.2f')` where the second argument is the required precision.

Comment: Sorry there was error in my earlier comment. See [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#inputarg_formatSpec) on how to use `num2str`.